# How to mock bean in springboot groovy and spock tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, spock

This is a spock test using groovy

This is my code

```
@SpringBootTest
class SrMetricServiceAspectTest extends Specification {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("potentialSrCreation")
private SrCreationService service

@MockBean
SrMetricService srMetricService

@TestConfiguration
static class TestConfig {

    @Bean("potentialSrCreation")
    SrCreationService getSrCreationService() {
        // Return an instance of PotentialSrCreation with necessary dependencies
        return new PotentialSrCreation()
    }
}
}
```

I have a groovy test in the structure of

```
def "..." () {
   given: 
      ...
   when:
      ...
   then:
      ...
```

However when I run the test, service itself is null. Is there an issue with my configuration/injection? I'm trying to define the bean within the test file.

Comment: 1.  ensure that  the application is running on the spring environment ,2.   if application is in spring  context ,pls try to  use ```@AutoWired``` which is provide by spring instead of  ```MockBean```  .  i  think that more likely  app is not in spring mode

Answer (score 0):

In the groovy with spock tests you should use `@SpringBean` to create and inject mocks into application context

```
@SpringBootTest
class SrMetricServiceAspectTest extends Specification {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("potentialSrCreation")
private SrCreationService service

@SpringBean
SrMetricService srMetricService

   //write tests

}
```

Using [@SpringBean](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/module_spring.html#_using_code_springbean_code)

> Registers mock/stub/spy as a spring bean in the test context.

> To use @SpringBean you have to use a strongly typed field def or Object won’t work. You also need to directly assign the Mock/Stub/Spy to the field using the standard Spock syntax. You can even use the initializer blocks to define common behavior, however they are only picked up once they are attached to the Specification.

> @SpringBean definitions can replace existing Beans in your ApplicationContext.